# Ref element returns null

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of elements returned from a class component, where I dynamically add and remove an element from that list...

```
class Page extends Component 
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {/****/}
        this.setParagraphRef = element => {
            this.paragraphNode = element;
        };
    }
 
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.paragraphNode) return;
        // Update this.paragraphNode after the paragraph list is updated
        this.setParagraphRef = element => {
            this.paragraphNode = element;
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id = "Page" ref={this.page} tabIndex="0" 
            className = "Page" onKeyDown={this.inputStream} >
                {this.state.keyboardStream.map((line) => (
                        <p ref={this.setParagraphRef} key={line.id} id={line.id.toString()} >
                            <span>
                                {line.text}
                            </span>
                        </p>
                 )}
            </div>
```

When a paragraph is deleted, the ref is set to null then updated. But sometimes it's not fast enough then I get an error. I have tried `React.createRef()` but this is even worse as I am not able to update it at all. I have also tried keeping an array of ref elements for each paragraph, but when they unmount, it does so in no order.

[Here is the complete project](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pine-vquw9?file=/src/page.js).

Comment: Can't you make a deeper decoupling? It may be necessary that you "enqueue" changes to the text holder, and let another component listen to them and perform the necessary changes.

Comment: @Pipetus, The `Page` component is the div that holds the list of the paragraph tags. Are you suggesting that I should make each `<p>` a component and they should have their own state?

Comment: From what I could see, things are messing up somewhere. I'm trying to identify if something is being executed after/before it should be, thus causing changes where there shouldn't be. My first thought was that you may need to change the approach, like having a single component handle the text (and not different streams), and that component to process changes that are committed by the other handlers. An indirection to what you already have.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be useful if you can narrow the scope: your whole project is a lot so as to suggest modifications on it.

Comment: ok, I would do just that. Right now I'm just focusing on the Page, keyboard functionality and how the mouse interacts with the page. No formatting, no copy & paste, no hotkeys/keyboard shortcuts. I have given myself many months to complete it and add any other features, this is just for learning.